# Using only python typing module to Type annotate a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, static, typing

I need to annotate `pandas dataframe` with `typing.Annotated`.

To make it concrete, I want something like in the attached image which comes from a presentation video but I'm missing where did the `kwtypes` come from? It doesn't seem to come from `typing` module.

```
from typing import Annotated
import pandas as pd

Dataset = Annotated[pd.DataFrame, kwtypes(
    name=str,
    age=int,
)]
```

Comment: Please post code, data, and results as text, not screenshots ([how to format code in posts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)). [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: @Barmar sorry it was a screenshot from YouTube. Now fixed.

Comment: When I google `kwtypes` I find it comes from Flyte.

Comment: ```from flytekit import kwtypes, task, workflow```

Comment: https://docs.flyte.org/projects/flytekit/en/latest/generated/flytekit.kwtypes.html#flytekit-kwtypes